# How to create a new paragraph within a list item?

Tags: google-docs

I am maintaining a Google docs document that contains questions and answers for programming tests in our university. It's public, so [you can see it](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1xU-GH9G1XEFpkIzB0hGSK1B1E2ShWE1iy9kp9ZwHjRA/edit#).

The problem I have is that every item is a list item.

1. Question 1
     Answer 1
2. Question 2
     Answer 2

I can add line breaks with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, but that's not a paragraph. This now became REALLY annoying because the Code Pretty plugin apparently cannot format only selected code, but formats whole paragraph. That, of course, includes question and answer text.

I'd like to make indented paragraphs for code within each answer (if it contains code). How to do that?

Should look like this, but what you see is a mess of newlines and tabs:

---

[image: image description]

Comment: Do you _need_ to use a list? I can think of a way to use a table with invisible borders to get the same effect. Otherwise, you need to manipulate paragraphs manually, and you still won't have a list. I don't think you can do what you want in Google Docs.

Comment: I don't need a list, but I need headings enumerated. And I also need to be able to create sub entries, such as `3.5`, `3.6` and so on. Sometimes answers are split to points, eg. when enumerating operators, keywords etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I found a hack to do this. Press enter to create new list item and then create a third one:

[image: image description]

The third item prevents you from being unable to continue the list later on. Now press tab to indent the second item:

[image: image description]

And finally, press back space to "delete" the indented item. It will become a paragraph:

[image: image description]

It prevents you from continuing the list though.

Answer (score -1):

Tomáš Zato answer is a good start. However if you like to continue the list, you can select all text in the list, convert it to a bullet point list, convert it back to a numbered list. And after that, clean up as mentioned by Tomáš